# Difference between ".", "::" and, "->"

Tags: c++, pointers, scope-resolution-operator

In c++ is there any difference between these 3 blocks of code:

```
MyClass->m_Integer // 1
MyClass::m_Integer // 2
MyClass.m_Integer  // 3
```

Comment: Make sure that you have [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  It is very difficult to learn the language--and learn to use it correctly--without a good book.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `->` and `.` operators are way to access members of an instance of a class, and `::` allows you to access static members of a class.

The difference between `->` and `.` is that the arrow is for access through pointers to instances, where the dot is for access to values (non-pointers).

For example, let's say you have a class `MyClass` defined as:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    static int someValue();
    int someOtherValue();
};
```

You would use those operators in the following situations:

```
MyClass *ptr = new MyClass;
MyClass value;

int arrowValue = ptr->someOtherValue();
int dotValue = value.someOtherValue();
int doubleColonValue = MyClass::someValue();
```

In Java, this would look like:

```
MyClass ref = new MyClass;

int dotValue = ref.someOtherValue();
int doubleColonValue = MyClass.someValue();
```

Comment: You can also use the `::` operator (called the scope resolution operator) to also refer to members of a namespace or a class.

Answer (score 6):

-> means MyClass is a pointer to the class and said pointer needs to be dereferenced in order to get to member m_Integer

:: is the scope or namespace operator.  It means that m_Integer is either static or needs you need to identify specifically which scope or namespace m_Integer is within.

. means that m_Integer is being access directly (not through a pointer) from MyClass.  It pretty much how you would access memebers from within Java as well and should be the one you are most familiar with.

Answer (score 6):

- `a::b` -- `a` is a namespace or a class (not an instance), and consequently `b` needs to be some static entity
- `a.b` -- `a` is an instance of a class and `b` is its member
- `a->b` -- same as `(*a).b` (`a` is a pointer to an instance of a class)

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other answers you've gotten, it's worth noting that `operator->` can be overloaded. You've already gotten some reasonable explanations of how the built-in version work, but an overloaded `operator->` is somewhat unusual, so perhaps it's worth adding a bit about how it works.

The standard describes how `operator->` is unusual fairly succinctly (§13.5.6):

> An expression x->m is interpreted as (x.operator->())->m for a class object x of type T if T::operator->() exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism (13.3).

This has a couple of implications:

1. Even though `->` looks like a binary operator, from a viewpoint of overloading, it's essentially a unary operator -- your overload will be a member function that takes no argument.
2. Your overload has to return one of two types: either a (reference to) an instance of another class that also overloads `operator->`, or else a pointer to some object (of class or struct type).

Since you can return an object that itself overloads `operator->`, an expression of the form `x->m` can hide an arbitrary amount of complexity (an arbitrary number of functions being called). What you write as `x->m` could really expand out to `x->y->z->a->b->...m`.